# Azure SQL Server - can't authenticate linked service from pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

So, I was provisioned an Azure SQL server into my subscription of Azure, and I am using Azure Data Factory. Well, starting to use it

The problem I ran into is the following.
I am able to connect
[image]
to Azure SQL Server database via

```
 - SQL Management Studio, 
 - via Visual Studio Code with SQL Tools extension, 
 - and with Azure data studio.
```

I was able to create tables and stored procedures.
All this I am doing by logging in using Authentication type

```
"Azure Active Directory - Universal With MFA"
```

.. and providing my "Active Directory Admin".  (The "Server Admin" does not work as I do not know what the password was when it was created and our sys admin said "it was blank" ??)
[image]

However, when I try to set up a **linked service** on Azure Data Factory and connect to the same SQL Server - I do not see that option (Azure Active Directory - Universal With MFA) in the drop down for Authentication type.

**Those available**

```
- SQL Authentication
- System Assigned Managed Identity
- Service Principal
- User Assigned Managed Identity
```

I tried them all, and I can't connect using either.
My understanding is that there is more to be done on the server management side, but I do not understand what.

Comment: Have a Sql user created in the database and connect with that user in the Data Factory.  Probably don't want the Data Factory using the database Admin anyway.  Having a separate user allows permissions to be set approprately.

Comment: can you share exactly what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `service principal` method to create a success linked service to your SQL database using Azure active directory authentication. You need to follow the steps below:

- First create an `app registration` in Azure active directory. Go to azure active directory and select `App registrations`.
  [image]

- Create a new app registration with certain name. As you can see in the above image, I have created it with the name `for_sql_db`.
- Since you already have set your SQL server with Azure Active directory admin, create a user using the name of the `app registration` created above. Assign this user any required role. I have used the following queries in my query editor of SQL database.

```
CREATE  USER [for_sql_db] FROM  EXTERNAL  PROVIDER;
ALTER  ROLE [db_owner] ADD  MEMBER [for_sql_db];
```

- Once the user is created in your SQL database, go to data factory to create linked service.
- Select the SQL server and database you want to create linked service to. Choose the Authentication as `Service Principal`.
- Then you can see `Tenant , Service principal ID and Service principal key`. Go to the **app registration** you have created. Here you can see Directory tenant ID and application client ID. Give them as following:

```
linked service Tenant: Directory Tenant ID
Service principal ID: application client ID
```

[image]

- For Service principal key, you need to create a secret in your app registration (for_sql_db).

[image]

- After creating the client secret, copy its **value** and use it as `Service principal key` in data factory linked service.
- You can see that, I have followed the above procedure and successfully created linked service to my SQL database.

[image]